# Openshift Nginx permission problem [nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)]

Tags: docker, nginx, openshift, root, alpine-linux

I am currently running into a problem trying to set up nginx:alpine in Openshift.

My build runs just fine but I am not able to deploy with permission being denied with the following error

> 2019/01/25 06:30:54 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
>
> nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)

Now I know Openshift is a bit tricky when it comes to permissions as the container is running without root privilidges and the UID is gerenated on runetime which means it's not available in /etc/passwd. But the user is part of the group root. Now how this is supposed to be handled is being described here

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-container-platform-specific-guidelines

I even went further and made the whole /var completely accessible (777) for testing purposes but I still get the error. This is what my Dockerfile looks like

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

#Configure proxy settings
ENV HTTP_PROXY=http://my.proxy:port
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=http://my.proxy:port
ENV HTTP_PROXY_AUTH=basic:*:username:password

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Install node.js
RUN apk update && \
    apk add nodejs npm python make curl g++


# Build Application
RUN npm install
RUN ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
COPY ./dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html

# Configure NGINX
COPY ./openshift/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./openshift/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chgrp -R root /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 777 /var
RUN sed -i.bak 's/^user/#user/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8080
```

It's funny that this approach just seems to effekt the alpine version of nginx. nginx:latest (based on debian I think) has no issues and the way to set it up described here

https://torstenwalter.de/openshift/nginx/2017/08/04/nginx-on-openshift.html

works. (but i am having some other issues with that build so I switched to alpine)

Any ideas why this is still not working?

Comment: I guess that you have set up a `user` in your `docker-compose.yml` file somewhere and that is what's causing the problem, because the user is a non-root user. The nginx service needs to bind ports and has to be root for that.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue, all errors removed after following `torstenwalter.de` link but still `nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)` remains. Though usnig `nginx:latest` instead of `nginx:alpine` fixed the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To resolve this. I think the Problem in this Dockerfile was that I used the COPY command to move my build and that did not exist. So here is my working

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

LABEL maintainer="ReliefMelone"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Install node.js
RUN apk update && \
    apk add nodejs npm python make curl g++


# Build Application
RUN npm install
RUN ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=${BUILD_CONFIG}
RUN cp -r ./dist/. /usr/share/nginx/html

# Configure NGINX
COPY ./openshift/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./openshift/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chgrp -R root /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 770 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Note that under the **Build Application** section I now do

```
RUN cp -r ./dist/. /usr/share/nginx/html
```

instead of

```
COPY ./dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The copy will not work as I previously ran the **ng build** inside of the container the dist will only exist in the container as well, so I need to execute the copy command inside of that container

Answer (score 21):

I was using openshift, with limited permissions, so I fixed this problem by using the following nginx image (rather than `nginx:latest`)

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
```

Comment: For anyone who are running a secure nginx in Openshift without root or the ability to edit the build, an option would be to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446840/issue-nginx-emerg-mkdir-var-cache-nginx-client-temp-failed-13-permiss to set required parameters in the nginx configuration

Answer (score 5):

Had the same error on my `nginx:alpine` Dockerfile

There is already a user called `nginx` in the `nginx:alpine` image. My guess is that it's cleaner to use it to run nginx.

Here is how I resolved it:

- Set the owner of `/var/cache/nginx` to `nginx` (user 101, group 101)
- Create a `/var/run/nginx.pid` and set the owner to `nginx` as well
- Copy all the files to the image using `--chown=nginx:nginx`

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN  touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
     chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx /var/run/nginx.pid
USER nginx
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx my/html/files /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx config/myapp/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
...
```

Comment: This works on my k8s using a random user id to start process

Answer (score 1):

If you're here because you failed to deploy an example helm chart (e.g: helm create mychart), do just like @quasipolynomial suggested but instead change your deployment file pull the right image.

i.e

```
containters: 
    - image: nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
```

more info on the official unprivileged image: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged

Answer (score 1):

May or may not be a step in the right direction (especially helpful for those who came here looking for general help on the `[emerg] mkdir() ... failed` error).

This solution counts from [Builing nginx from source](https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html).

It took me about seven hours to *realize* the solution is directly related to the prefix path set in compiling nginx.

This is where my configuration throws off nginx (as a very brief example), compiled from this [nginx source](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/branches/stable-1.18):

```
sudo ./auto/configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/nginx \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/tmp/nginx/client-body-temp \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp
```

Without realizing it, I was setting the prefix to `/usr/local/nginx` but setting the **client body temp path** & **fastcgi temp path** to a directory inside `/tmp/nginx`.

It's basically breaking nginx's ability to access the correct files, because the temp paths are not correlated to the prefix path.

So I fixed it by (again, super simple configure as an example):

```
sudo ./auto/configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/nginx \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/usr/local/nginx/client_body_temp \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/usr/local/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
```

Further simplified:

```
sudo ./auto/configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/nginx \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/client_body_temp \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/fastcgi_temp \
```

Again, not **guaranteed** to work, but definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the folder using the nginx.conf file. You can read more information in the section [Running nginx as a non-root user](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

Answer (score 0):

Find openshift uid and gid

```
$oc describe project <project_name>
```

outputs:
annotations:

```
          openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups=1001240000/10000
          openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range=1001240000/10000
```

Nginx configurations files (sample):

#### nginx_default.conf

```
server {
    
      listen 4200;
      server_name supp-homolog.procuradoria.go.gov.br;
    
      sendfile on;
    
      default_type application/octet-stream;
    
      gzip on;
      gzip_http_version 1.1;
      gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
      gzip_min_length   1100;
      gzip_vary         on;
      gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
      gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
      gzip_comp_level   9;
    
    
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    
      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      }
    
    }
```

#### nginx.conf

```
user  root;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

### Setup Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine as build
 
RUN chgrp -R 1001240000 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 770 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chown -R 1001240000 /run

COPY --chown=1001240000:1001240000 docker/dev/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --chown=1001240000:1001240000 docker/dev/nginx_default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

 HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD curl --fail http://localhost:4200/ || exit
 
 EXPOSE 4200
 CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

#### Sample Deployment

Specifying the securityContext

```yaml
kind: DeploymentConfig
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
 [...]
spec:
  [...]
  template:
    [...]
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-test
          image: >-
            image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/<project_name>/nginx-test:latest
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsGroup: 1001240000
            runAsUser: 1001240000
```

### Dockerfile (complete angular example)

From angular root folder:

```
$ podman build -t myapp . -f Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine as build

RUN apk add tzdata
RUN apk add python3 make g++
ENV TZ America/Sao_Paulo
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8512

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/node

FROM build as dev

WORKDIR /app

# Copy angular source files
COPY . /app

RUN npm install npm@9.6.7 -g  && npm install

# build (ng build), output to dist folder
RUN node --max_old_space_size=8512 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration development

FROM nginx:stable

RUN chgrp -R 1001240000 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 770 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chown -R 1001240000 /run


COPY --from=dev --chown=1001240000:1001240000 /app/docker/dev/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=dev --chown=1001240000:1001240000 /app/docker/dev/nginx_default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy angular dist folder to nginx
COPY --from=dev --chown=1001240000:1001240000 /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN find /usr/share/nginx/html/ -mindepth 1 -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD curl --fail http://localhost:4200/ || exit

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score -3):

run the below command to fix the above issue. The anyuid security context constraint required.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid system:serviceaccount:<NAMESPACE>:default
```